# CSS heading with flexible decorative images on either side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a decorative heading with horizontal lines either side, similar to http://www.impressivewebs.com/centered-heading-horizontal-line/ but with the following constraints:

- Support arbitrary header text
- Fluid - stretches to fit the width of the page
- The horizontal lines are images - each line is comprised of a decorative "tip" image, and then a repeating section which should stretch as far as needed to fill the page width
- The decorative tip images are fixed widths (297px each)
- Solution must work with background image on web page
- As the page width shrinks, the repeating sections of the images get smaller and eventually disappear. The heading text in the middle then wraps onto multiple lines, if necessary.

I am trying to use CSS only for the solution, although I would consider JavaScript help if it cannot be done with pure CSS.

I have seen a few similar questions on SO, but I don't think that any of the solutions would do quite what I'm looking for.

Here is my own naive attempt (also at http://jsfiddle.net/39qLr/1/). For simplicity I have coloured the "tip" images in red, and the flexible repeating images in yellow. The obvious problem is that the yellow parts are not showing up right now!

HTML:

```
<div class="heading-container">
    <div class="left-tip"></div>
    <div class="left-filler"></div>
    <h1>Heading Text</h1>
    <div class="right-filler"></div>
    <div class="right-tip"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left-tip, .right-tip {
    background-color: red;
    width: 297px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.left-filler, .right-filler {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

I am very grateful for any guidance!

Comment: can you not define a width for the filler, because then they show up

Comment: @Vogel612, I would like the fillers to fill the remaining space between the tip images and the header text. So the width of the filler will depend on the width of the page and the width of the header text. I have updated the question to make that clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from a colleague, we have managed to get as close as we think is possible:

http://jsfiddle.net/rbCvq/

HTML (same as before):

```
<div class="heading-container">
    <div class="cell left-tip">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell left-filler">&nbsp;</div>
    <h1 class="cell heading-text">Heading Text</h1>
    <div class="cell right-filler">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell right-tip">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.heading-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
}

.left-tip, .right-tip {
  width: 297px;
  background: red;
}

.left-filler, .right-filler {
  background: yellow;
}

.heading-text {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The secret sauce that makes it work seems to be:

- the 1px width on the heading element
- adding the `white-space: nowrap`
- the `nbsp;` in the empty DIVs

Of course this doesn't fulfil my original criteria of making the text wrap onto multiple lines, but I think the overall effect works about as well as we could hope. Also, the markup is a bit heavy on the DIVs, which serve no semantic purpose.

Thank you for all the suggestions, and I hope this is useful to somebody else one day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something close to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/39qLr/2/

I pushed the images inside your fillers, so that you can leverage position aboslute within relative.  Which will afix them to the ends.

Fiddle with your widths to get it right and mind the height.

```
<div class="right-filler">
        <div class="right-tip"></div>
</div>

.left-tip, .right-tip {
    background-color: red;
    width: 297px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
.left-tip{
    left:0;
}
.right-tip{
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure that this will work since it relies on percentage widths for the text and fillers (in the jsFiddle at least) and I would like the result to look good at arbitrary page widths and with arbitrary heading text. I have edited my question to make this clear.

Comment: Just trying to help you get moving in the direction you desire.  The site isn't a place to have someone code out your full solution.

Comment: I realise that, and I am very grateful for all ideas.